# Combine 2 countor plots into 1 graph

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a code that produces 2 countor plots, I want to combine them into 1 graph. How can this be done? I dont know where to put in `hold on` or if you even need to use it. Tried to put it some different places but it never worked.

code:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-2.5 : 0.02:2.5, -2.5 : 0.02: 2.5);
s = x + 1i*y;

    z=abs((1+(3/2)*s+sqrt(1+s+(9/4)*s.^2))/2);

    figure;

    [C,h] = contour(x,y,z,[1 1]);
    clabel(C,h)


    z=abs((1+(3/2)*s-sqrt(1+s+(9/4)*s.^2))/2);
    figure;

    [C,h] = contour(x,y,z,[1 1]);
    clabel(C,h)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're creating two figures by calling `figure` twice so regardless of where you put `hold on`, the contour plots will always appear in different figures.

Instead, call `figure` once and call `hold on` *in between* the calls to `contour` to prevent one from over-writing the other.

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-2.5 : 0.02:2.5, -2.5 : 0.02: 2.5);
s = x + 1i*y;

z=abs((1+(3/2)*s+sqrt(1+s+(9/4)*s.^2))/2);

figure;

[C,h] = contour(x,y,z,[1 1]);
clabel(C,h)

hold on

z=abs((1+(3/2)*s-sqrt(1+s+(9/4)*s.^2))/2);
[C,h] = contour(x,y,z,[1 1]);
clabel(C,h)
```

[image]